# Code subtracting 1 or 2 characters

Tags: r

If I have a list for example:

```
 Userid    Total
Apple1    12
Apple2    8
Apple3    15
Apple4    3
Apple5    4
Apple6    6
Apple7    20
Apple8    22
Apple9    5
Apple10   11
Orange1   15
Orange2   8
```

but I want to do calculations of all Apple items in general, how do I subtract the numbers from the end, I have a code that works if it is a single digit, however I do not know what to do when it becomes double digit.

I currently am using:

```
substr(userid, 1, nchar(userid)-1)
```

, which would work for Apple1-9 however Apple10 would then be Apple1, any suggestions what to do.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do on that subset? Your answer to that can affect the answer for how to subset the data.

Comment: I want to rank that subset by which has the highest total, however by looking at the separate userids (aka all the Apples), therefore I want to have the userid for all to be just Apple instead of having the number at the end

Answer (score 1):

try `gsub` to replace all numbers:

```
x <- c("Apple10", "Apple3", "Orange123")

gsub("[0-9]", "", x)
#[1] "Apple"  "Apple"  "Orange"
```

This means, check each element of `x` and replace any numbers with nothing.

Or, if your data was in a data.frame called `df`:

```
df$Userid <- gsub("[0-9]", "",df$Userid)
```

Now you can procede with ordering as you wish

Comment: I think this actually works for what I am looking for!

Comment: @beginneR Another read suggests you are probably right. I thought the current unintended result was the desired result. +1

Answer (score 0):

Using the stringr package, and a different approach:

```
require(stringi)
x <- c("Apple10", "Apple3", "Orange123")
str_replace_all(str = x, pattern =  "\\d{1,3}$", replacement = "")

[1] "Apple"  "Apple"  "Orange"
```

The pattern to be replaced by "" is 1 to 3 digits at the end of a string.